# What is the recommended approach for raising database-triggered events with NServiceBus? Is direct SQL Service Broker integration no longer viable?

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4

My team is currently in the initial stages of designing implementations using NServiceBus (v4, possibly v5) in a number of different contexts to facilitate integration between a number of our custom applications.  However we would also like to utilize NServiceBus to raise business events triggered from some of our off-the-shelf third-party systems.  These systems do not provide inherent messaging or eventing apis, so our current thinking is to hook into their underlying databases using triggers and potentially SQL Service Broker as a bridge to NServiceBus.

I've looked at [ServiceBroker.net](https://github.com/jdaigle/servicebroker.net%20ServiceBroker.net) but that seems to use NServiceBus v2 or v3 api's, interfaces, etc., by creating a totally new ITransport.  We're planning on using more recent versions of NServiceBus though, so this doesn't seem to be a solid option.  Other somewhat similar questions here on SO (all from a few years ago) seem to be answered with guidance to simply use the SQL Transport.  That uses table-based pseudo-queues instead of MSMQ, but what's not clear is if it is then advisable to have SQL triggers hand-craft NServiceBus message records and manually INSERT them into the pseudo-queue tables directly, or whether there would still be some usage of SQL Service Broker in the middle that somehow more natively pops the NServiceBus messages onto the bus.  And if somehow using the SQLTransport is the answer, what would be best practice to bridge the messages over to the main MSMQTransport-based bus?

It seemed like there was some concerted movement on SQL Service Broker bridging over to NServiceBus several years ago, but was deprecated once the native NServiceBus SQLTransport was introduced. I feel like maybe I'm missing something in terms of the modern NServiceBus approach to generating data-driven events in a design that is more real-time than a looped polling design.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [Gateway](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/the-gateway-and-multi-site-distribution) feature.  You should be able to run 2 different transports and use the Gateway feature to bridge the two via HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar system, although it's slightly easier in that we control the underlying databases and applications (i.e. not 3rd party) and the current proof of concept uses the ServiceBroker / SQLDependency / ServiceBus as part of its architecture.

If you go this route, I would also advise using triggers to populate a common table, then monitoring that.

I didn't know about ServiceBroker.Net until today, so can't comment. I also haven't looked at CLR stored procs / triggers; whether there's any possibilities there.

Somebody else asked a question about nServiceBus and ServiceBroker which I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27319292/1818795) which may be useful for anyone looking to implement this.